# IE8: element:first-child deosn't work (selects parent of what I actually want)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Works in chrome, not ie8: http://jsfiddle.net/a7rXZ/2/

so, when you click on accepted, decline, or open, it changes the text adjacent to the little click menu (while maintaining styling of the text on the left (this is ideal)). but in IE, it seems to be replacing the parent element (cause the styling of the text doesn't remain the same)

any ideas for how to get this to behave in IE8?

this is the code in question:

```
$j('.change_option').click(function() {
    $j('#change_status_menu').fadeToggle("fast");
    $j(".status .status_header span:first-child").attr("class", $j(this).html());
    $j(".status .status_header span:first-child").html($j(this).html());
    $j('#proposal_status').val($j(this).attr("name"));
    unsaved_changes = true;
});
```

Comment: There are a few problems here, notably you are filling the `class` attribute with HTML, the mark-up has `<div>` inside `<span>` elements and the text of the badges is outside the `<div>` elements. I suspect with cleaner mark-up this problem might solve itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect IE just has a problem with mark-up in `class` attributes. I wouldn't blame IE though since it's totally invalid. The solution is really a case of making the mark-up cleaner and copying only the relevant sections of text/mark-up from the *options* to the *status header*.

I've cleaned up the mark-up a little and re-worked the jQuery to select only the `text()` and `class` necessary for manipulating the `status-header` element. Basically, I've turned the options into an unordered list, rather than using a combination of `<div>` and `<span>`. So it might not be exactly what you are after, since I am not sure if you can change the mark-up and I have also removed the the `.badge` class.

The problems were mainly that the JavaScript was adding HTML content into the class attribute of the `.status-header span` element, but also a lot of the text in the example was outside any element, so the JavaScript was actually selecting too much content each time. The other problem I could see was that you had already duplicated the mark-up for the secondary status heading, so rather than replacing this HTML each time, it was easier to just extract the one class ('Open', 'Accepted' or 'Declined') and the text of the *option*.

There is more that can be done to simplify the code, for example the `.class` and `text()` being copied to the header are now exactly the same so should be simplified.

Here is a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zkRLp/) which is working for me in Chrome and IE8

For completeness, here is all the code:

#### HTML

```
<div class="proposal_status">
    <div id="change_status_menu" style="">
        <div class="change_status_menu">
            <ul class="container">
                <li class="Open" name="1">Open</li>
                <li class="Accepted" name="2">Accepted</li>
                <li class="Declined" name="3">Declined</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="arrow_border_2"></div>
        <div class="arrow_border"></div>
        <div class="arrow"></div>
    </div>

    <input id="proposal_status" name="proposal[status]" type="hidden" value="2">
    <div class="status">
        <div class="status_header">
            <span class="Accepted">Accepted</span>
            <div class="action_button change_status">Change Status</div>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <div class="prop-status-details">
                Accepted by 
                <strong>aoei eui</strong> from 
                <strong>127.0.0.1</strong>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(function() {
    $j(".change_status").click(function() {
        $j('#change_status_menu').fadeToggle("fast");
    });
    $j('li').click(function() {
        $j('#change_status_menu').fadeToggle("fast");
        $j(".status .status_header span").attr("class", $j(this).attr('class'));
        $j(".status .status_header span").html($j(this).text());
        $j('#proposal_status').val($j(this).attr("name"));
        unsaved_changes = true;
    });
});
```

#### CSS

```
.no_padding{
    padding: 0px !important;
}
.properties-shell {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    width: 930px;
    position: relative;
    border-right: solid 10px #f3f3f3;
    border-left: solid 10px #f3f3f3;

}
.properties-shell-top {
    margin-top: 15px;
    background: url(../images/bucket_wide_bg.gif) no-repeat;
    width: 950px;
    height: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.properties-shell-bottom {
    background: url(../images/bucket_wide_bg.gif) 0 -10px no-repeat;
    width: 950px;
    height: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.properties-main {
    background: #FFF;
    display: table;
    border-left: solid 1px #e5e5e5;

}
.properties_header{
    border-right: solid 1px #e5e5e5;

    display: block;
    height: 38px;
    border-top: rgb(229,229,229);
    background: #e5e5e5;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, 
        color-stop(0%,#e5e5e5), 
        color-stop(96%,#f2f2f2), 
        color-stop(97%,#ffffff), 
        color-stop(98%,#e5e5e5)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #e5e5e5 0%, #f2f2f2 96%, #ffffff 97%, #e5e5e5 98%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #e5e5e5 0%, #f2f2f2 96%, #ffffff 97%, #e5e5e5 98%); /* Opera11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #e5e5e5 0%, #f2f2f2 96%, #ffffff 97%, #e5e5e5 98%); /* IE10+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e5e5e5', endColorstr='#e5e5e5',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    background: linear-gradient(bottom, #e5e5e5 0%, #f2f2f2 96%, #ffffff 97%, #e5e5e5 98%); /* W3C */
}
.properties_first_col{        
    padding: 20px;
    width: 415px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
.properties_second_col{
    padding: 20px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    width: 210px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
.properties_options{
    background: #F7F7F7;
    float: right;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 187px;
    border-left: solid 1px #e1e1e1;
    border-right: solid 1px #e1e1e1;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #e1e1e1;
    min-height: 268px;
}

.option_select{
    padding: 5px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #747474;
}

.proposal_status {
    position: absolute;
    top: 266px;
    right: 0px;
    margin-right: 1px;
}
.change_status_menu {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: rgba(235,235,235, 0.95);
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    width: 142px;
    height: 110px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 77px;
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);

}
.change_status_menu .container{
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.change_status_menu .container li {
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    padding:5px 0 5px 10px;
    margin:0;             
}

.change_status_menu .container li:hover{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 2%, #e9e9e9 96%, #F3F3F3 85%, #e9e9e9 96%, #ffffff 98%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    padding-left: 9px;
}
.arrow {
    z-index: 1003;
    border-color: #EDEDED transparent transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    height:0;
    width:0;
    position:absolute;
    right: 38px;
    bottom: 60px;
}
.arrow_border {
    z-index: 1001;
    border-color: #d3d3d3 transparent transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    height:0;
    width:0;
    position:absolute;
    right: 38px;
    bottom: 58px;
}
.arrow_border_2 {
    z-index: 1002;
    border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    height:0;
    width:0;
    position:absolute;
    right: 38px;
    bottom: 59px;
}
.proposal_status .status{
    width: 227px;
}
.proposal_status .status .status_header,
.proposal_status .status .Unpublished{
    background: #e5e5e5;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, 
        color-stop(0%,#e5e5e5), 
        color-stop(96%,#f2f2f2), 
        color-stop(97%,#ffffff), 
        color-stop(98%,#e5e5e5)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #e5e5e5 0%, #f2f2f2 96%, #ffffff 97%, #e5e5e5 98%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #e5e5e5 0%, #f2f2f2 96%, #ffffff 97%, #e5e5e5 98%); /* Opera11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #e5e5e5 0%, #f2f2f2 96%, #ffffff 97%, #e5e5e5 98%); /* IE10+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e5e5e5', endColorstr='#e5e5e5',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    background: linear-gradient(bottom, #e5e5e5 0%, #f2f2f2 96%, #ffffff 97%, #e5e5e5 98%); /* W3C */

    width: 227px;
    height: 30px;
}
.proposal_status .status .status_header .change_status{
    width: 88px;
    font-size: 9px;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.proposal_status .Accepted,
.proposal_status .Declined,
.proposal_status .Open{
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #848484 !important;
    text-shadow:#fff 0px 1px 0, #fff 0 -1px 0;                    
}
.proposal_status .Accepted .badge,
.proposal_status .Declined .badge,
.proposal_status .Open .badge,
.proposal_status .Unpublished .badge{

    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 3px;
}
.proposal_status .Accepted .badge{
    background: url(/images/header_status_green.png) no-repeat;
}

.proposal_status .Declined .badge{
    background: url(/images/header_status_blue.png) no-repeat;
}

.proposal_status .Open .badge{
    background: url(/images/header_status_grey.png) no-repeat;
}

.proposal_status .Unpublished .badge{
    background: url(/images/header_status_white.png) no-repeat;
}

.proposal_status .status .info{
    background: #F2F2F2;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, 
        color-stop(0%,#F2F2F2), 
        color-stop(100%,#D6D6D6)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #F2F2F2 0%, #D6D6D6 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #F2F2F2 0%, #D6D6D6 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #F2F2F2 0%, #D6D6D6 100%); /* IE10+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#F2F2F2', endColorstr='#D6D6D6',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    background: linear-gradient(bottom, #F2F2F2 0%, #D6D6D6 100%); /* W3C */
    box-shadow: inner 0 2px 2px #bbb;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px #bbb;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.prop-status-details {
    padding: 10px;
    color: #5F5F5F;
    line-height: 15px;
}
.proposal_status .status .Unpublished{
    margin-top: 95px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-indent: 10px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #818181;
    text-shadow:#fff 0px 1px 0, #fff 0 -1px 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.action_button {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #FCFCFC;
    border: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #8B8B8B !important; 
    text-transform:uppercase !important;
    /*    text-shadow: #555 0px -1px 1px;*/
    /*    letter-spacing:1px;*/


    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 18px;

}
.action_button:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #f4f4f4;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation! It's good to know what is actually going on =D

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're setting the `class` attribute with html content. I've done a quick workaround:

http://jsfiddle.net/a7rXZ/4/

Simply changing `.html()` with `.text()`. The original returns a value that looks like the following (yes, including all the whitespace):

```
                <div class="badge"></div>
                Declined
```

But you're expecting just the text `Declined`, which is retrievable by the new version. You might like to consider a slightly stronger tactic (whitespace removal would be a start, but I'm referring to something more rigid), even though for now the new version works.